# Why the object will be created when I pass it to a method?

Tags: php, function, oop, object

Here is my code:

```
public function call_with_attempts($class_obj, $method_name,array $params = [], $attempts = 5) {
    while ($attempts-- > 0) {
        try {
            if (call_user_func(array($class_obj, $method_name), $params)['result_code'] == '01') {
                // log success
                return $class_obj->$method_name();
            }
            throw new Exception("failed");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            trigger_error($e->getMessage());
            // log the error
        }
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
$url = 'www.example.com';
$obj = new Profile($url);
all_with_attempts($obj, 'mymethod');
```

And here is `Profile` class:

```
class profile {

    public $url;

    public function __construct( $passed_url  )
    {
        $this->url = $passed_url;  
    }

    public function mymethod(){
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

---

Any my code *(when I call this function `all_with_attempts($obj, 'mymethod');`)*. throws this error:

> Missing argument 1 for App\classes\Profile::__construct(), called in {/path}

As you know, this error ^ means `Profile` class will be create again .. well that's not what I want. I want to use `$obj`. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe check if the passed parameter is an object first: `if(is_object($class_obj))` and if so, then use `if(method_exists($class_obj,$method_name))` then return that class with that method or else if you pass a string, then use use the `call_user_func()`?